# Atom package grammar regular expression flag for case insensitivity

Tags: regex, grammar, atom-editor

I am following [a tuturial](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-write-a-syntax-highlighting-package-for-atom/) on creating a package with grammar for syntax highlighting in Atom.
My language is case-insensitive, e.g. `define` is equivalent to `DEFINE`.

Atom seems to be running [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), but it seems flags are not supported in the cson grammar configuration file

```
    'match': '(DEFINE)'
```

It seems there is [no documentation](http://flight-manual.atom.io/search/?q=grammar) about grammars.

How can case-insensitive matching be achieved?

Comment: Are you sure it is JS regex flavor? Still, try adding `(?i)` at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: They seem to use another regex library, and your hint is correct. I just found it in the documentation below. The package is in `atom\app-1.11.2\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\oniguruma`.

Comment: Please explain the downvote so I can improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a special group:
https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE#L197

```
'match': '(?i)(DEFINE ...
```

Comment: It is not a group. A modifier group is `(?i:DEFINE)`.

Comment: Note that Oniguruma != JavaScript's regular expression engine. It is an [open issue](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/571) that the find-and-replace feature in Atom uses JS regexes, even though [Oniguruma **is** used to parse grammar files](https://discuss.atom.io/t/regular-expression-lookaround-support-in-find/12400).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You may be right but the referred documentation file uses the term "extended groups".